# js window.matchMedia returns wrong result

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to check the physical size of the viewport, so I can omit less interesting columns from a table to make the table more readable on a phone.

```
MaxWidth = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 5in)").matches;
```

seems to do the job on my computer with a 24" screen: If the browser uses the full screen, MaxWidth is false, if I shrink the window, Max will be true at some point. On my smartphone however, MaxWidth is always false.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry folks, the error was somewhere else!
I forgot the meta tag

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in the html file. This way my pages looked quite "unexpected".

Just in case someone has the same effects -  check this tag in the head of the html file ;-)